# ¿Como verificar si existe una sesion y evitar que entre por una URL directa?

Tags: php, sesiones

quisiera saber como validar si existe una sesion en una pagina php , en caso de que no exista me envie a la pagina de login,ya que , no ha verificado que exista una sesion , de esta forma evitar que entren de forma directa por URL , por ejemplo :

> [www.dominio.com/dashboard.php](http://www.dominio.com/dashboard.php)

Saltandose el login y entrando el sistema sin estar logeado , he intentado algo como esto pero no ha funcionado :

```html
<?php

session_start();
$usuario = $_SESSION["username"];

if (!isset($usuario) || empty($usuario)) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Para que haces esa asignación intermedia? Usa directamente la variable super global...

Comment: Tal como tienes el código seguramente te da un error de PHP en tu archivo log de errores de tu dominio cuando esa variable $_session no está establecida, pero quizás no lo ves porque quizas tu nivel de error_reporting() es demasiado bajo. Haz lo que te pide @DavidJP y te saltaras el error (que no ves) y te funcionará el condicional.

Comment: @DavidJP Gracias David!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un sistema como el siguiente donde **control.inc** realiza la validación de sesión :

login_action.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include "db.php";
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = '$username' and password = md5('$password')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if($result == false) {
  echo '<a href="login.php">Error: cannot execute query</a>';
  exit;
}

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows == 1) {
  $_SESSION["login"] = "OK";
  $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
 $redirect = "private.php";
}
else
 $redirect = "login.php";

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);

header("Location: $redirect");
?>
```

control.inc

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(!(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "OK")) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

private.php

```
<?php
  include "control.inc";
  include "header.php";
  include "menu.inc";
?>

<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>
<a href="exit.php">Exit</a>
</p>

<?php   
  include "footer.php";
?>
```

exit.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Es un ejemplo antiguo ya que mysql_query esta obsoleto, pero te podría funcionar para entender la lógica, sino con clases que lo verifiquen todo pero seria diferente.